# Linq to sql: orderby not working

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this method and I have not been able to order my result. It wont order at all.
    Do you know what am doing wrong ?

```
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetBranches()
            {
                List<SelectListItem> objList = null;
                var strQuery = (from sl in _objDataCollection.Edmm_Tester
                    orderby sl.Code
                    select new SelectListItem() {Text = sl.Name, Value = sl.Code}).Distinct();

                objList = strQuery.ToList();

                return objList;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
objList = strQuery.OrderBy(e=>e.Code).ToList();
```

Or this:

```
  var strQuery = (from sl in _objDataCollection.Edmm_Tester
                select new SelectListItem() 
                {
                  Text = sl.Name
                , Value = sl.Code
                }).OrderBy(e=>e.Code).Distinct();
```